# In the new BigQuery client library - load job - how to set a custom null marker?

Tags: java, google-bigquery

In the new BigQuery api (com.google.cloud.bigquery), is there an option to set a custom null marker?

I know how to do this through the command line api:
`bq load --null_marker='\N'`

But can't find a way to do it through the java client.

In other words, is there a java equivalent to this:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load.nullMarker

Comment: As far as I can tell, that's just a missing feature - I suggest you file a github issue to request it. (I suspect it would be fairly easy to add to `LoadJobConfiguration`.)

Comment: For other reader's sake, Daniella already created a feature request, which is tracked here:
https://buganizer.corp.google.com/issues/37658884